# boost::filesystem How having a correct path to file read it into stringstream?

Tags: c++, file, boost, boost-filesystem

So I have a `path` `p` and I can call for example `is_regular_file(p)` and `file_size(p)` on it but how to read that file into stringstream? (btw I need only to read it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to copy the entire file into the `stringstream`.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::ifstream( p.string().c_str() ).rdbuf();
```

Here is a kind of inside-out demo:

```
Shadow:code dkrauss$ ./ssclone ssclone.cpp 
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char *argv[] ) {
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::ifstream( argv[1] ).rdbuf();

std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @Blender: So, specify `ios::binary` as a second argument to the `ifstream` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

boost::filesystem::path has string method.

const std::string & string() const;

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_path

ss << p.string ().c_str ();

Comment: I mis-understood the question.  I thought you wanted the path/file name of the file in the string.